# How to quickly prompting available name when use input existence name in java back end

Tags: java, jpa, db2, eclipselink

### Now I have a requirement.

When user input a existence name, 
I need to quickly prompting available name to user.
And in the front end , there is no problem.
But in the back end, **how to code a sharp code?**

This function is like when user use name 'Java' to register a email account, when found duplicate, will give user some availble name suggestiong like 'Java01', 'Java001', 'Java002'

Currently, my idea as follows,
**Example**:

User input name is '**Name01**'.
First I use 'JPQL(JPA)' to validate the name is existence;
If existence, I will create a sql like '`Select name from table a where a.name like 'Name01%'`
Then I will get a existence name list.`{'Name012','Name014','Name015'...}`
 So I use the **'Name01'** to general a guess list
like `{'Name010','Name011','Name012','Name013','Name014',...}`
And Then I use the guess list to compare the existence name list, and return a 10 size list(which should not existence in db, user can use one of them to save the request quickly to avoid the second validate .) like: `{'Name010','Name011','Name013','Name016',...}`

But if the guess list all existence  in db. 
I will need to search db by 'Name0%' and do the 
recursion.
It seems so inefficient.
I am confused **how to general a guess list and how to compare that will reduce the compare frequency.**
Any one have good solution ?

Tips: I use JSF+EJB+JPA(Eclipse Link 1.0) DB2 The name's max length is 10, can only contain character.

Comment: how about something like results = em.createQuery("select entity.name from Entity entity where entity.name = :p1 OR entity.name like :p2").setParameter("p1", inputName).setParameter("p2", inputName+"%").setMaxResults(11).getResultList()?  What is inefficient in the query?

Comment: o, sorry, I mean I need to give user 10 size name list (which should not existence in db, user can use one of them to save the request quickly to avoid  the second validate .).

Comment: I don't know of a way to query for what isn't in the database, only what is.  You can use the query provided so that it hits the database only once and gives you what is there.  You would have to generate a list of what you want - the user name plus 10 options on it, and remove the ones from it that exist as returned from the query.

Comment: One thing i recommend if you are using JPA, is to try to solve your problem using named queries(`@NamedQueries`). This will definitely decrease the amount of times you hit the database.

Comment: @sfrj how does a `@NamedQuery` help decrease DB hits? My understanding is that it is [just a shorthand for a query that is defined elsewhere](https://blogs.oracle.com/JPQL01/entry/named_query_in_java_persistence). Some people like to write all their JPQL in their metadata and not have it appear as `String`s in their DAOs and this allows them to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Efficient data structure to use in this situation is a [`Trie`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (Prefix Tree).

As part of your application you should generate a `Trie` with all the `Name`s and this data structure can be used to generate the user prompt. The beauty of this data structure is that it reduces the time complexity to `O(n)`.

eg: name0,name10,name45 will produce a Trie with following nodes

```
root node - "n"
node Level 1 - "a"
node Level 2 = "m"
node Level 3 = "e"
node Level 4 = "0" , "1" , "4"
node Level 4 = "0" , "5"
```

Comment: refer following link to get more idea about tries : [link] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: Thanks.How about put the guess list and existence list in two HashSet ? And use  guess HashSet to call removeAll method to remove the existence HashSet?

Comment: I don't know how on Earth a `Trie` got interpreted as a `Set` for the `guess` and `exists` values - but with that bounty, who cares :-P

Answer (score 2):

To be honest ... I find it very frustrating that very intelligent web apps are actually suggesting something like ricky01 or ricky011 and stuff like that.

We are still humans and the reason we comeup with nicknames is to avoid having to memorize IDs, which, more or less is what would eventually happen in a system providing suggestions like %01

Wouldn't it be a better idea just to suggest the username that your user already has choosen for something with a much higher visibility like his/her email address?

E-mails are by definition unique and you can play along like google does: "If you enter email@domain.com" then first check if email is his valid username else check the whole thing...

I guess that what I'm saying is that you'll end up with a much user friendlier system.

Comment: Thank you .I very agree with you ideas. But the requirement is come up with the client. I have no choice.

Answer (score 0):

probably you can pre-define generating rules first:

for example, if users' input exists and then you concatenate this input with some random generated letters and numbers to produce 10 size suggestion list, and then use one query to verify them available. because this list is really seldom not avaible for use, most of time you will succeed, while if not, just generated list again.

```
userInput = "java"
generate list = {"java01","java02","java03",...}
select count(*) into existence from table a where a.name in (list)
if existence >0 then regenerate else return list
```

so just define a rule first to generate rules for suggestion list and keep this algorithm nearly succeed for the first time and also the suggestion close to users' wants.

Answer (score 0):

As Byter has pointed out, a [`Trie`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) is the most optimal object type to use. However, finding a Java implementation that would be easy to use is tricky. Taking the second best option, and sticking to standard classes, how about this for a hack? (Assumes your users are using UTF-8)

```
import com.google.common.collect.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Subsearch {

    private static final List<String> EXAMPLE_RESULTS = Lists.newArrayList("Name010", "Name011", "Name012", "Name013", "Name014", "Name100");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // EXAMPLE_RESULTS is from the DB lookup, also retain the original user string
        // exit if the user didn't add one character to the end of the original string
        SortedSet<String> sorted = Sets.newTreeSet(EXAMPLE_RESULTS);
        String userInput = "Name0";
        String upper = userInput + "\uFFFF";        
        SortedSet<String> trimmed = sorted.subSet(userInput, upper);
        // save "trimmed" and userInput for the next iteration
        // no need to store EXAMPLE_RESULTS anymore
        System.out.println(trimmed);
    }
}
```

I caveat this with the following: make sure you actually need to optimise your lookup code. If the DB is not suffering from the hits then don't introduce this extra layer of complexity (extra code to maintain plus an increased possibility of concurrency issues). It is entirely possible that if you have indexed your `@Column` then the DB might actually be using a `Trie` internally.

Incidentally, you have indexed your column, right? If not, you can do so by adding the following Hibernate-specific annotation to the field

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Index
@Column
String name;
```

(Don't forget to rebuild the DB Schema) or by issuing a [native query](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you have few steps:
1) user enters their preferred userName (free text entry with NO restrictions, maybe few rules)
2) you validate user entry from above and either accept it if it is unique or present user with few alternatives (do you disable user free text entry at this point?)
3) you accept user selection from step 2) (without further validation because you assume that it will be unique already?)

It is NEVER a good idea to assume anything and accept ANY user data without validation, for this reason step 3) will have to perform the same validation as step 2) - it means that there IS no step 3), there is just a repeated step 2).

That leaves functionality in step 2)

Query your user store (DB) to check if the entry is unique:

a) it is unique - create new entry and inform the user

b) it already exists - query your user store for LIKE entries, usually it will be userEnteredStringFromStep1 + someWayOfMakingYourStringUnique. Most commonly someWayOfMakingYourStringUnique is just a number. So, you need to query your user store for LIKE 'userEnteredStringFromStep1%' and generate new userEnteredStringFromStep1 + someWayOfMakingYourStringUnique combinations which are not present in your result from above.